# Calling interactive script with PHP results in keyboard input problems

Tags: php, docker, shell, symfony, command

I am writing a small Symfony Console Application that needs to be able to initiate some interactive shell scripts/commands. For example, I have a Symfony Command that enters a bash shell in a docker container.

I used `passthru` to achieve this:

```php
class BashCommand extends \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command {
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        passthru('docker exec -it my-container bash');
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, this works pretty well. If I execute this command via `./console app:bash`, I enter the bash shell of the container and can work with it.

However, there are problems with my keyboard layout or rather certain interactions in this docker bash shell openend by PHP and `passthru`. Arrow keys to navigate in that bash shell don't work, they only print invalid characters. CTRL+C also reacts weirdly, probably because it conflicts with the PHP process still running in the background. I have also tried entering a `mysql` shell with `passthru` - same problem.

Is there any other way I can call such an interactive terminal command from a PHP script, without breaking the terminal input? It seems to me, that the underlying PHP process somehow interferes with the terminal. Is there a way to call that shell command basically after PHP has exited? There are some shutdown-methods in PHP, but my guess is that that is still too soon.

My workaround is to also have a non-PHP regular bash-script, that calls such commands "natively". In that case the terminal works just fine.

Comment: Is the OS that you are running the Symfony commands itself (that you are typing on) Windows-based?

Comment: It's CentOS. The Docker Container I'm targeting is using Debian.

Comment: Okay, nevermind. I asked because I know of a bunch of weirdness, and a couple of workarounds when running PHP on the CLI for Windows, but I guess that doesn't apply.